# Meaning of this Og midrash

Tags: agada-stories-legends

[image]

So what’s the meaning of this midrash exactly? Do any commentaries talk about what it could represent, what 60 represents, etc…

Comment: 60 is a common example of a large number, meaning "a lot."

Comment: @ElonMusk Yes this was common I think in societies that had base 60 system like Babylon. Egypt, Moab, and Israel though generally used 40 more often for the same purpose.

Comment: @setszu Israel had a base-40 system?

Comment: @ElonMusk No lol, I was just saying that in Babylon which was a base 60 system, they used 60 to mean "a lot" or a "long but unspecified period of time" more or less, while Ancient Egypt, Moab, Israel, etc. used 40 though I'm not sure why, its not because they were base 40 though (they weren't)

Comment: @setszu I knew they didn't, it just sounded like you were saying they did lol

Comment: I don't think any culture had a number system based on a since number base until relatively recently.  Even modern imperial measurements use different bases for lbs/oz, floz/pint/gallon, inch/foot/yard/mile etc so the 40/60 thing seems pretty normal